# Adding an extra field to mail()

Tags: php, email, contacts

I tried asking this before but I think I made things too complicated and nobody answered. This is take two. I need to add a phone number field to this line of PHP. I have NO IDEA how to add it.

```
mail( "contact@jeremyblaze.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );
```

I've tried this, but the email never goes through.

```
mail( "contact@jeremyblaze.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['text'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );
```

Here's the full PHP if you need it.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

    $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
            exit;
        }
    }

    mail( "contact@jeremyblaze.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] );

}
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried just replacing `$_POST['text']` with `$_POST['phone']` and the phone number appears in the message's body on its own.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No, I don't. I am not a PHP developer.

Comment: You're trying to add the phone number to *what*? You haven't stated what you're actually trying to accomplish. Where is the phone number to be used?

Comment: Jeremy, I am not sure why Jonathon is being so nasty :( - check out Pathfinder's answer. You're mail command is not formatted correctly.

Comment: @Damien I'm not being nasty. The OP *still* hasn't told us where he wants the phone number to end up in this ordeal.

Comment: @jonathon - sorry if I took your commentary the wrong way. It's fairly obvious to me that the OP doesn't normally code in PHP and just wants it to appear in the body of the message like a normal contact form would, likely separated into another line as suggested by pathfinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this 
Your are doing wrong way.Add proper subject and message.Please study this link for [details](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

```
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'Your subject and add phone no here';
mail('contact@jeremyblaze.com', $subject, $message);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. (Because the question is invalid and can't be answered.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I think question is valid but he didn't know how to write mail function properly.

Comment: The reason I say it's invalid is because he wants to `"add a phone number field to this line of PHP"` and hasn't told us what the phone number is supposed to do or where it's supposed to end up.

Comment: Agree that's why i put an example with link to mail function for further study.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the php mail function page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You cannot add the phone number inside the function like that.

Here is the basic function:

```
mail(email,subject,body);
```

You need to add the phone number to the body of the text:

```
$email = "contact@jeremyblaze.com";
$subject = "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'];
$body = "From: ".$_POST['email']."\n\r\n\rPhone: ".$_POST['phone']."\n\r\n\r".$_POST['text'];

mail($email,$subject,$body);
```

You should really look at the documentation on the php site:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

It will show you how to set additional headers for reply-to and from, etc. But what I gave you should make what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement @Mahmood Rehman info, if you want send a HTML e-mail you can do this:

```
            // From
            $email_from = $vEmail;

            // To
            $to  = 'contact@jeremyblaze.com';

            // Subject
            $subject = $vSubject;

            // HTML Message
            $message = "<html>
            <head>
            <title>Title</title>
            </head>
            <p><b>$vName</b> send the follow message:</p>
            <p><b>Subject:</b> $vSubject</p>
            <p><b>Message:</b> $vMessage </p>
            <p><b>E-mail:</b> $vEmail </p>
            <p><b>Phone:</b> $vPhone </p> 
            </body>
            </html>";

            // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: $email_from\r\n";

            // Mail it
            mail($to, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", $message, $headers);
```